# Get .txt file from Lotus Notes document using Java

Tags: java, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I created the notes doument using java code and then created the rich text field as follow

```
           doc = db.createDocument();
            doc.replaceItemValue("FROMMAIL", "sender@gmail.com");
            doc.replaceItemValue("SENDTO", "receiver@gmial.com");
            doc.replaceItemValue("SUBJECT", "NotesSlrWriter");
            DateTime s2 = sess.createDateTime(new Date());
            System.out.println("Setting date to: "
                    + s2.toJavaDate().toLocaleString());
            doc.replaceItemValue("POSTEDDATE", s2);

            RichTextItem t = doc.createRichTextItem("Attachements");
            t.appendText("Here is the Attachment");
            t.addNewLine(2);
            t.embedObject(EmbeddedObject.EMBED_ATTACHMENT, null,
                    "c:\\test\\test.txt", "testtxt");
            doc.save();
```

So i know from using  doc.getItemValue(arg0) values i can get the values of the other field in my java code.

But i don't know how i can get test.txt in a Attachment field of Notes Document into my java class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case if you do not know the file name, you can walk through all attachments in RichTextItem.

Below is example that scan 1 richtextitem and export all files in folder.

```
RichTextItem body = doc.getFirstItem("Attachements");
Vector v = body.getEmbeddedObjects();
Enumeration e = v.elements();
while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
   EmbeddedObject eo = (EmbeddedObject)e.nextElement();

   if (eo.getType() == EmbeddedObject.EMBED_ATTACHMENT) {
         System.out.println("\t" + eo.getName());
         eo.extractFile("c:\\extracts\\" + eo.getSource());
         eo.remove();
   }
}
```

There is another solution, that may help you:

```
EmbeddedObject eo = doc.getAttachment("testtxt");
System.out.println(eo.getName());
eo.extractFile("c:\\extracts\\" + eo.getSource());
```

Comment: Thanks for reply but your code i tried it giving me an error "java.util.Vector cannot be cast to lotus.domino.RichTextItem" , on this line                                  RichTextItem body = (RichTextItem) doc.getItemValue("Attachements"); Attachement is my RichText field.

Comment: when i am doing this  RichTextItem body = (RichTextItem) doc.getFirstItem("Body"); i am getting body variable as null but why  i am getting that null value, please help?

Comment: @shreerambanne try to avoid casting like that RichTextItem body = doc.getFirstItem("Attachements");

Comment: You got the null pointer because your code executes getFirstItem("Body"), but rich text item is not named "Body". You named it "Attachements" in your code.

Answer (score 1):

`t.getEmbeddedObject("testtext")` will give you an `EmbeddedObject`.

The doc for the `EmbeddedObject` class is [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.0/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_NOTESEMBEDDEDOBJECT_CLASS_JAVA.html).